# Hard-Coding Categories or Fetching from API

Tags: foursquare

What is the recommended method of getting CategoryIds. I understand Foursquare provides this list: https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree. My question is should I just use this list and hard-code the values or fetch the Ids on first opening of the app and caching these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [venues/categories](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories) API documentation:

> When designing client applications, please download this list only once per session, but also avoid caching this data for longer than a week to avoid stale information.

So fetch on app launch and cache for the current session to insure the hierarchy is always up-to-date.